# Level 6 Part 1 Help

Tags: vim-adventures

I'm at the first part of level 6 (the first character countdown):
[image: Level 6]
And I only have WwEeBb:
[image]
I can't for the life of me figure out how to get to the red section in 7 keystrokes (saving 2 for dW to remove the word) - did I miss some actions/keys? How do I pass this section?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the question -- an excuse to return to Vim Adventures for the first time in a while!  Thanks!!

I've just confirmed that it's possible to edit that text in the required keystrokes, with the keys you have now:
[image: My keys collection matches yours early in Level 6.]
[image: I edited the 'asdf ' word with strokes to spare.]

My keys collection matches yours early in Level 6, and I edited the 'asdf ' word with strokes to spare, releasing a yellow key.

Without giving too much away -- I didn't do it on the first pass through; and it really helps to approach it backwards.

I hope that helps; and if you're still stuck, I'll give a more complete answer.

Comment: Ah, that helps a lot - for some reason I just didn't consider that as a possibility.