# Level 6 Part 1 deleting asdf

Tags: vim-adventures

The same question has already been asked ([here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/271469/level-6-part-1-help)), but I'm still stuck after reading the hint given there. To end up at the "e" in "err" (so I can use `db` to delete the letters in red) I am trying to reach the "e" in "stare", but this is as close as I can get (so I would need 2 more keystrokes).

Is there an alternative to trying to go down using the "j" key? If that's the only option, we'd need to reach across to the "e" in "err" in one keystroke, which seems impossible to me. What am I missing?

[image]